# Configuring a logstash.conf file to create multiple indices when given one input containing several sources

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

My goal is to output filtered data into different indices. On my logstash.conf file, I currently have one input that takes in data from multiple logs files and then I filter the data as follows:

```
 filter {
    if ([source] ~= "examiner.log") {
       json {
       source => "message"
       add_tag => ["EXAMINER"]
       }
   } else if ...
      ...
   }
}
```

My output looks like:

```
output {
 if ("EXAMINER" in [tags]) {
    elasticsearch {
    host => ["localhost:9200"]
    index = "examiner"
    } 
 } else {
     elasticsearch {
     host => ["localhost:9200"]
     index => "data"
     }
  }
}
```

The data index gets created, but examiner never does. I'm not sure why the conditional does not seem to be working.

An example of my input data is:

```
{"@timestamp":"2019-09-27T20:42:12.254Z", "source_host":"WINL12345678", "file":"AppStarter.scala", "method":"start", "level":"INFO", "line_number":"34", "thread_name":"pool-1-thread-1", "@version":"1", "logger_name":"org.http4s.server.AppStarter", "message":"Application is running", "class":"org.http4s.server.AppStarter$class", "mdc":{}}
```

Comment: Does your documents in the data index have the `EXAMINER` tag? Also, it should be `=~` in your filter, not `~=` ([documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals))

Comment: No I only added this tag for the examiner.log

Comment: Try to correct your condition in the filter, use `=~`, and test the output without filtering by the tag, to see if your filter is working. Can you share a sample of your input data, before entering in the logstash pipeline?

Comment: Would I also be able to try to output based on source? I tried that instead of the tag but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: I just tested the output to see if it had the tag in kibana, and it doesn’t so it turns out the filter isn’t working properly